# How to handle referenceError in typescript getter function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

In typescript, I have a project with a **Database** object that is an **array of 
Cinema** objects. I also have a **throwif** function. The following code does not produce any error:

```
function throwIf(condition: boolean, message: string){
    if (condition) return new Error (message)
}

function getCinema(cineId: number, database: Database): Cinema {
    throwIf(cineId == null, 'cineId should not be null')
    throwIf(database == null, 'database should not be null')

    let cinema = database
        .find(cinema => cinema.id === cineId)

    if (!cinema) throw new Error (`No cinema with id : ${cineId} `)
    return cinema
}
```

but I'd rather write it like this :

```
function throwIf(condition: boolean, message: string){
    if (condition) return new Error (message)
}

function getCinema(cineId: number, database: Database): Cinema {
    throwIf(cineId == null, 'cineId should not be null')
    throwIf(database == null, 'database should not be null')

    let cinema = database
        .find(cinema => cinema.id === cineId)

    throwIf(!cinema,`No cinema with id : ${cineId} `)
    return cinema
}
```

but it throws a compiler error :

```
Type 'Cinema | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Cinema'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Cinema'.
```

Is there any way to make it work ? **without** typing the return value as Cinema|undefined ?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want this: `function getCinema(cineId: number, database: Database): any{`.

Comment: @sr9yar You never want `any` in *any* place it could be avoided.

Comment: @estus, It defeats the purpose, I agree :) It seems to me, there should be completely different logic in those functions otherwise...

Comment: @sr9yar how would you do it ? I'm okay to change the whole logic of it too, just want to find the best solution with a getter and a way to throw errors :)

Comment: Maybe you should define your cinema type from the start `cinema: Cinema;`, because you return value must be `Cinema`

Comment: @sr9yar throwIf and `if (!cinema) throw` are very close, the problem is just that throwIf cannot be statically analyzed to be type guard. You won't be able to define it like `cinema: Cinema` because this will result in type error when `Cinema | undefined` is assigned to it. But it's possible to assert the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if` acts as [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types).

There are [user type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) that can be useful in similar cases but it isn't applicable here because it's supposed to return a value and be used with `if`.

Functions like `throwIf` cannot be statically analyzed by the compiler to work as type guards. There is [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8655) that shows Node.js `assert` as an example of this limitation.

It's possible to address this with non-null assertion:

```
...
throwIf(!cinema,`No cinema with id : ${cineId} `)
return cinema!;
```

Since `throwIf` will require to consistently use non-null assertion afterwards:

```
throwIf(!cinema,`No cinema with id : ${cineId} `)'
console.log(cinema!);
return cinema!;
```

Or reassign a variable with a no-op:

```
throwIf(!cinema,`No cinema with id : ${cineId} `)'
cinema = cinema!;
console.log(cinema);
return cinema;
```

Or assert it beforehand (can affect types a in negative way prior to `throwIf` call):

```
let cinema = database.find(cinema => cinema.id === cineId)!;
```

`throwIf` in its current state cannot be considered practical in TypeScript; it isn't considerably shorter or more readable than respective `if (...) throw ...` statement.

Comment: Thank you @estus, this is the kind of information I needed ;)